# Pharo Smalltalk - Is there a way to force deallocation (dealloc) on an Object (instance) (expire sessions etc) during Seaside development?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

When you want to garbage collect a certain instance, what message can you send it?

I'm hacking away at a Seaside based app, and a lot of things ca go haywire, including my RootComponent having 10 instances (is this normal), and I'd like a fresh start (not a fresh image)

Later edit: After reading a bit, apparently the question is anathema in the Automatically Garbage Collected world, so let me rephrase.

Comment: Maybe this is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019664/garbage-collect-certain-object

Comment: You are right it is partly related, however I have this eerie feeling when developing in Pharo Smalltalk. This "live" development environment never actually gives you a chance to test "program flow" from the beginning. You might allocate some Objects and then change the way the allocation happens, so now it doesn't work any more and there is no other way to test it but to 'nil' variables so lazy initialization kicks in. I was wondering if there is a workflow I'm missing out on that makes everything start 'fresh' each time.

Comment: Assignment destroys the old references, so you might not want to go to the trouble of assigning to nil. There are other workflows that you could ask about in a new question (perhaps in a forum or Programmers.SE ?) For example, you can export your program to source control, like Monticello, and import it into a clean image. Squeak and Pharo projects' Jenkins servers do something like this for some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make the VM garbage collect a specific object. You can evaluate `Smalltalk garbageCollect.` to force garbage collection but that will simply trigger the garbage collection mechanism of the VM for all objects.

There are usually two problems here (in my experience):

1. garbage collection in the Pharo VM uses two different algorithms for two separate phases (I believe they are "mark-and-sweep" and "scavenge"). A single `Smalltalk garbageCollect.` might thus not be sufficient to actually remove the object. You will often see code like `3 timesRepeat: [ Smalltalk garbageCollect ].` which tries to ensure that an object gets collected. Note also that some special objects are protected from garbage collection (like `nil`, `true`, `false` etc.).
2. in certain situations the garbage collection algorithm does not seem capable of resolving all obsolete objects. I've seen this happen with the Morphic event mechanism. There, an event is simply a closure in the context of a method. Even if the registered objects have been garbage collected, some events will hang around (if the responsible object didn't unregister them correctly), creating entire graphs of objects that can't be collected (since the root can't be collected). I suspect that the actual problem is some kind of circular dependency. Note that this is an exceptional case and that forced garbage collection works quite well in general.

With that said, we've been using Seaside for close to a decade now and garbage collection is usually one of our least concerns. When we need something garbage collected / cleaned up, nilling the variables and forcing garbage collection (3 times) does the trick.

#### Edit

In Seaside 2.8 you can evaluate `WARegistry clearAllHandlers.`, in Seaside 3 that is roughly equivalent to `WAAdmin clearAll.`. These statements will clean up active and expired sessions and trash most of the stuff you might be concerned about.
Note: `#clearAll` will also clear configurations and registered entry points. Use `#clearSessions` if you only want to reset the sessions. Use `#clearAll` if you require a more thorough clean up.

#### Edit 2

Use `myObject pointersTo.` to find all the pointers pointing to a particular object. You can also right click on an entry in the GTInspector and click on "open pointers to".

You might also want to check out [PointerDetective](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/%7EBenComan/PointerDetective), which tries to graphically represent the pointer finding process.

Comment: Thanks for Edit 2. On topic: WAAdmin clearAll causes http://localhost:8080 to reply with a 404 and /config or any other page with a not found. However registering back an application works and one can visit /WhateverRoot just fine. Configuration seems to be gone?

Comment: You're right. `#clearAll` is very eager to "clear all". I updated my answer.